# Godot save Items i have collected

Tags: save, 2d, godot, gdscript

I am working on a platformer game in Godot Engine where i have a Hub World that will house the entrances to all the individual levels, but i would like to save what items i have collected within the individuals levels so that once i finish the level or reach a checkpoint and return back to the hub world, it knows what items i picked up. I don't know what the best way to do this would be

I only want it to save what items i have if the level is actually finished or a checkpoint is reached, if i simply quit out of the level having collected some items but never reached a checkpoint or completed the level, i want them to still be there

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to store what items the player has collected in a file which you'll update when the player reaches certain checkpoints, and read from to find out what items the player has. You can google "Godot save game" to get some ideas on how to actually implement this.